# Why is there a gap between header and section?

Tags: css, frontend

I have added relevant HTML and CSS

I set margin of header to `0 auto` but there is still a white space between header and section. How come?

And what is the exact difference between setting margin like `0 5` and `15px`?

This is the CSS code:

```
header{
    text-align:center;
    background:blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1,h2{
    color:black;
}

nav a{
    color:#fff;
}

section{
    background:orange;
}
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Jack Yuan | Web Developer</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="TreeHouse/normalize.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="TreeHouse/main.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <header>

            <a href="First.html" id="logo">
                <h1>Jack Yuan</h1>
                <h2>Web Developer</h2>
            </a>

            <nav>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="Portfolio.html"class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="About.html"class="selected">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </header>

        <section>
            <ul id="gallery">
                <li>
                    <a href="TreeHouse/Jack.jpg">
                    <p> This is me </p>
                    <img src="TreeHouse/Jack.jpg" width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="TreeHouse/Life.jpg">
                    <p> This concludes my life, lol </p>
                    <img src="TreeHouse/Life.jpg"width="500" height="400"  alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="TreeHouse/Study.jpg">
                    <p> This shows what I study </p>
                    <img src="TreeHouse/Study.jpg"width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="TreeHouse/2.jpg">
                    <p> This is what I believe</p>
                    <img src="TreeHouse/2.jpg"width="500" height="400" alt="">
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/jackyuan.jack">
            <img src="TreeHouse/facebook.gif" alt="FaceBook Logo">
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/Jack19909100">
            <img src="TreeHouse/twitter.png" alt="Twitter Logo">
            </a>
            <p>Jack Yuan</p>
            <p>All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: without your code, we won't be able to help you...

Comment: Could be a border, the section might have margin, or something else.  There is no way for us to tell w/o looking at your code

Comment: Setting margin like 0 5 means margin-top and margin-bottom is 0 and margin-right and margin-left is 5. Setting margin: 15px; means 15 px margin all around [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp). Section is below your header right? maybe section has a top margin.

Comment: Great, we are getting there, CSS is needed **but** we will also need your HTML code because we can't guess how the elements are aranged in the markup.

Comment: @web-tiki  Yup got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this CSS :

```
ul,p {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/9jF6A/)**

I would also suggest you use som kind of CSS reset styleshhet like [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [this one](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it!

Comment: @JackYuan Glad I could help, don't forget to upvote/accept the answer if it helped. More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @JackYuan well now you know how to ask questions so rep will come if ask some more. But you can still accept answer by clicking on the tick (left top of this answer).

Comment: I am wondering why this is the solution though... since the gap is between section and header, why can't it be header,section{ margin:0;}@web-tiki

Comment: @JackYuan You may check this article http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/ or this one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing if you want to understand collapsing margins.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of margin collapse.